# How to show date with timezone in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, timezone

i am using angularjs filter date. i have used this one

```
 var date = new Date("09 apr 2015 12:00:50 UT");
 $filter('date')(date, "dd MMM yyyy  hh:mm:ss a Z");
```

Output:

```
 09 Apr 2015 08:19:04 PM  +5:30
```

i need output:

```
09 Apr 2015 08:19:04 PM GMT +5:30 (IST)
```

Answer (score 3):

i don't think you can do it out of the box with plain angular.js, but you can use a library like [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment). 
moment.js supports variety of formats: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: That seems to be the case. Angular documentation for date filter does not mention timezones in other form than +XXXX: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date.